# Is it possible to change the "Pods" directory created by "pod install"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Is it somehow possible to change the `/Project/Pods` directory to something like `/Project/SomeFolder/MyPods`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change path in podfile as below:

```
workspace '../ejourna.xcworkspace'

target 'project' do
    platform :ios, '13'
    use_frameworks!
    project '../ejournal.xcodeproj'
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: ah.. great idea

Comment: and is it also possible to rename the "name" pods?

Comment: @MartinMlostek No, i never saw config changes about it. And in Cocoapods source code 'Pods' name is hard coded